# pandas acting weird with np.where

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm using np.where to convert price_level(str) to price(str)

```
df['price'] = np.where(df['price_level'] == '1', '$', 
                                  np.where(df['price_level'] == '2', '$$', 
                                  np.where(df['price_level'] == '3', '$$$', 
                                  np.where(df['price_level'] == '4', '$$$$', ''))))
```

does not work for '4'.
This is the output:

```
df
price_level price
0   2   $$
1       
2   1   $
3       
4       
5       
6   2   $$
7       
8       
9   4
```

even though

```
df['price_level'] == '4'
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: price_level, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me (`9   4  $$$$`) under numpy 1.16.4 and pandas 1.1.5.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `np.select`

```
con1 = df['price_level'] == '1'
con2 = df['price_level'] == '2'
con3 = df['price_level'] == '3'
con4 = df['price_level'] == '4'

df['price'] = np.select([con1, con2, con3, con4] , ['$','$$','$$$','$$$$'])
```